# Return field by name as ambiguous object

Tags: java

The code I have currently,

```
public UUID uuid;
public long login;
public long logout;

public static enum Key {
    UUID,
    LOGIN,
    LOGOUT;
}

public User(UUID u) {
    uuid = u; // only the uuid needs to be set here
}

public Object get(Key key) {
    // return the object
}
```

How can I get the field by lowercasing the enum, then return as ambigious object in the "get" method as shown above?

Comment: Why do that? You have 3 enums and 3 fields, use an `if-else-if`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've not heard or seen that before, can you show me an example?

Comment: And why do you want to do this instead of using standard getters?

Comment: There will be a lot of fields. Using 1 getter & 1 setter for each field makes for a really cluttered class.

Comment: Reflection? It could be useful

Comment: All the getters and setters is standard Java practice, though, and many tools expect it. If you don't like the boilerplate (I don't), use Groovy; it'll generate them implicitly and you don't have to wade through them.

Answer (score 0):

The other comments are valid but if you need to use enums...
How about define the fields as an Array of Objects?
Note: you will need Long the Object not 'long' the type.

Comment: What about the UUID? It needs some love too :P

Comment: long cant be casted to object and vice versa?